# How to create the table with column having not null and primary key in hive?

Tags: hadoop, hiveql

I am beginner in hive. I am using cloudera 5.10.0 version.
I tried the below query to create the table:

```
create table categories1 (category_id INT NOT NULL, category_department_id INT, category_name varchar(45), PRIMARY KEY (category_id));
```

But it shows the below error

```
FAILED: ParseException line 1:42 mismatched input 'NOT' expecting ) near 'INT' in create table statement
```

In below link it has mentioned that how to create the constraint but I am unable to create it.
https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+DDL#LanguageManualDDL-Constraints.

Please let me know how to create column having not null value and primary key in Hive 1.1.0-cdh5.10.0.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hive 1.1.0 does not support constraints. Documentation says: As of Hive release 2.1.0.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because OP asks about feature which is not supported in his Hive version, and documentation which OP is referring clearly says about it. Hive 1.1.0 does not support constraints.  Constraints added in Hive release 2.1.0. OP uses Hive 1.1.0

Comment: Thank you.I Will update the version.